# Copy from 1 sheet vertical range to horizontal row sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I'm starting to get back into vba after many years and have forgotten more than I remember and wondered if  anyone might be able to help.

I'm looking to copy data from sheet 1, particular cells and then add it to the next blank row so that it pastes horizontally and not vertically.

The code below works fine except each item pastes to the next row down rather than horizontally across the row if that makes sense?

```
Sub AddEntry()

Range("I11, I13, I15, I21").Copy

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use "transpose" parameter.Not sure if it would work for excel 2003 and earlier versions though

```
Sub AddEntry()

    Range("I11, I13, I15, I21").Copy

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    Application.CutCopyMode = False    

End Sub
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you! I knew there was something I forgot!